# what is the fourier transform of exp(-a*x^n) where a is a constant and n is an integer

Tags: polynomials, exponential-function, fourier-transform

I need help finding the fourier transform of this function, particularly because I am working with zernike polynomials so I need to find the Fourier transform of exp(-C0*Z0-C1Z1-...CNZn) where C are coefficients and Z are Zernike Polynomials that can be expressed in either cartesian or spherical coordinates defined over a circle of unit radius

Comment: See [Wolfram Alpha's result](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=fourier+transform+exp(-a*x%5En)).

Comment: no result. I have tried this for closed form using Mathematica. A) it takes  too long to compute B) crashes for large n

Comment: Sorry can't help.

Comment: I don't know the answer except when $n=2$, which you also know or can look up. But you might note that if $n$ is odd that function does not _have_ a Fourier transform. (Not even in the sense of distributions; $e^{-x^3}$ is not a tempered distribution...)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich if it helps the polynomial either x or y is only defined in unit circle. So x ranges from -1 to 1 and same for y

Comment: I have absolutely no idea what it means to ask for the Fourier transform of $e^{-ax^n}$ "where $x$ ranges from $-1$ to $1$". And I don't see any $y$. Maybe you could state more preciselyy exactly what function you want the transform of?

Comment: For $n =3,4,5,6,7,8...$ Mathematica `11.3` can solve and gives answer by `Gamma` and   the generalized `Hypergeometric` functions.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich an optical system defined over a unit circle can be described using zernike polynomials. This polynomials are in form of x and y, you can see the full list here. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zernike_polynomials
 then we must calculate the pupil function which is  exp(-C0*Z0-C1Z1-...CNZn). Finally to calculate the point spread function one must find the absolute square of the Fourier Transform of the pupil function. Since the pupil function is an exponential with terms that are being added and can be separated, I want to be able to generalize for one term, FT of exp(-a*x^n)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk just tried for n=15. Still running. It's even worst if I try to compute a 2D fourier transform for polynomials Z(x,y). I was hoping someone could direct me to a paper related to this